# Nextjs Image not using the height value

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I am new to NextJS and was using its Image tag to have an image in my application. But the image size only changes if I change its width value, changing height's value does not impact it at all.
Here is the image:

```
<Image src="/Logo.png" alt="Logo" height={10} width={100} />
```

Here the image is taking the width's value and coming out to be big. If I replace the values in height and width, then also it takes the width's value and becomes small. I have even tried to put height property after width but nothing changes.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Version of nextjs?

Comment: Its version is 13.0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the Image component inside a div and style it like this:

```html
<div style={{ position: "relative", width: `${100}px`, height: `${10}px` }}>
    <Image
        src="/Logo.png"
        alt="Logo"
        fill
        style={{ objectFit: "contain" }}
    />
</div>
```

Note that:

- The wrapper div has a relative position since `fill` Images are absolute positioned inside the DOM
- `fill` is a prop in next 13 (older versions use `layout="fill"`)
- `objectFit` is passed inside the style object (with optional `objectPosition`) and those properties will be added to the rendered `span` element style properties

Comment: If you are using Tailwind, Just Styling the image div with your preferred width and height, then replace the width and height properties in the image tag with the fill={true} and just as @eroironi.co said remember to add relative to the div tag since fill are absolute positioned inside the DOM. that did  the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap  tag in a  with the height and width you want your image to be

Add layout="fill" in the  tag

```
<div style={{width: '100px', height: '100px'}}>
  <Image
    src="/Logo.png"
    alt="Logo"
    layout='fill'
    objectFit='contain'
  />
</div>
```

Comment: `layout="fill"` and `objectFit="contain"` don't exist in next 13 (version of the OP's project), instead the props `fill` and `style` can be used